# Compare a group of rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table having coloumns,

```
ID    |       BRANCH    |       START_NUM      |    END_NUM  
123             S                    25                95
234             S                    45                105
445             S                    46                90
556             M                    56                129
78              M                    76                199
87              M                    80                110
987             M                    89                128
777             M                    100               1500
```

I want to first group my result on basis of `BRANCH`(M,S Here).Then i want only those records which lies insubset of  `MASTER START AND END NO` which is being the first row of a group.Here i will compare `S` group with `25-95` and in `M` group with `56-129`.
Hence answer is (i am just writing rows first element)

```
123
445
556
87
```

Comment: What do you mean with "first row of a group"? Do you mean the one with lowest `START_NUM`?

Comment: Why wouldn't `987` be in result set ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below given query in MSSQL.

```
SELECT B.ID FROM Branch B
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT M.BRANCH,C.START_NUM,C.END_NUM
        FROM BRANCH M
        OUTER APPLY(
            SELECT TOP 1 START_NUM,END_NUM
            FROM Branch
            WHERE BRANCH = M.BRANCH
            ORDER BY START_NUM
        ) C
) L ON B.BRANCH = L.BRANCH AND B.START_NUM >= L.START_NUM AND B.END_NUM <= L.END_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right (I think I do) and assuming that *"first row of a group"* is according to `start_num` order, then you can try:

```
SELECT ID, BRANCH, START_NUM, END_NUM
FROM
(SELECT ID, BRANCH, START_NUM, END_NUM
, min(START_NUM) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY START_NUM) over (partition BY BRANCH ) st
 , min(END_NUM) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY START_NUM) over (partition BY BRANCH ) en
FROM table1) t
WHERE t.START_NUM >= t.st AND t.END_NUM <= t.en
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/add18/6)

Comment: when i am trying to run it in my table,it says invalid identifier

Comment: Maybe because of the `""` remove them and try again (I updated my answer as well)

Answer (score 0):

(1) How do you define the "first" row for the group? I am assuming it is the row with the lowest start number for that branch.

(2) If there is a tie, for instance let's say for your M group, there are 2 rows with the same start number, but a different end number. Would the range be that of the start and end for the row having the highest end value, or the lowest end value?

The answer to question #2 above is important so I'll give you the sql for both.

**If you want the lowest END_NUM where there are 2+ rows in the same BRANCH with the same START_NUM**

```
with boundaries as(
select id, branch, start_num, end_num
from tbl y
where start_num = (select min(x.start_num) from tbl x where x.branch = y.branch)
  and end_num = (select min(x.end_num) from tbl x where x.branch = y.branch and x.start_num = y.start_num)
)
select x.*
from tbl x join boundaries y on x.branch = y.branch
where x.start_num >= y.start_num
  and x.end_num <= y.end_num
```

**If you want the highest END_NUM where there are 2+ rows in the same BRANCH with the same START_NUM**

```
with boundaries as(
select id, branch, start_num, end_num
from tbl y
where start_num = (select min(x.start_num) from tbl x where x.branch = y.branch)
  and end_num = (select max(x.end_num) from tbl x where x.branch = y.branch and x.start_num = y.start_num)
)
select x.*
from tbl x join boundaries y on x.branch = y.branch
where x.start_num >= y.start_num
  and x.end_num <= y.end_num
```